# How to delete video from Vimeo account through vimeo api

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

In my previous asked question [How to upload video in vimeo account through vimeo api in Symfony 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677794/vimeo-api-not-working-in-symfony-2-2)   which is now closed . Now I have one more requirement that I want to delete the uploaded video from vimeo account through my application with help of vimeo api into which i used the

> "vimeo.videos.delete"   method
>   as given below

```
/**
 * Deletes a Video entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="video_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $vimeo = new phpVimeo('my_api_key', 'my_api_key_secret', 'my_token', 'my_token_secret');
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->bind($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $video = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Video')->find($id);

        if (!$video) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Video entity.');
        }
    $videoId = $video->getVideoId();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        try
        {
        $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.delete',array('video_id',$videoId));
        $em->remove($video);
        $em->flush();
    }
    catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
            echo "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
        }
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('video'));
    }
}
```

But when i try to delete a selected video in my application , it try to delete the video but can't delete the video from vimeo account while from my database references infos of this video is deleted while i want to delete the video from the both database and vimeo account . I do't konow what wrong I m doing ?

If any help regarding this issue is available to anyone , please help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: Please do not answer your question by edditing it and put (solved) in title. Insted Post an answer an accept it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now By a little bit change in my coding i have solved it !

```
/**
 * Deletes a Video entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="video_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->bind($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $video = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Video')->find($id);

        if (!$video) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Video entity.');
        }
    $videoId = $entity->getVideoId();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        try
        {
        $api = $this->api();

        $method = 'vimeo.videos.delete';

        $query = array();
        $query['video_id'] = $videoId;

        $r = $api->call($method, $query);

    }
    catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
            echo "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
        }
        $em->remove($video);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('video',array('result'=> $r)));
    }

 public function api()
{
    $consumer_key = 'my_api_key';
    $consumer_secret = 'my_api_key_secret';

    $token = 'my_access_token';
    $token_secret = 'my_access_token_secret';

    $vimeo = new phpVimeo($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $vimeo->setToken($token, $token_secret);

    return $vimeo;
}
```